# Как сделать чтобы мой сайт находился оп русским словам к примеру "Купить мобильный телефон"

Tags: seo

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы мой сайт находился в поисковике по фразам вроде "купить мобильный телефон, ремонт компьютеров и т.д.", а не только по прямой ссылке

Answer (score 0):

Грубо говоря, он должен содержать эти фразы и должен быть проиндексирован поисковыми системами.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо чтобы страница, которая должна выводиться по запросу, отвечала бы как минимум этим требованиям:

- Имела бы ключевые слова в метатеге: `<meta name="keywords" content="купить,мобильный,телефон">` (рядом поисковиков [игнорируется](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/41356546?hl=ru), но [Yandex может учитывать эту информацию](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.html) при определении релевантности)
- Имела бы описание вроде `<meta name="description" content="описание, релевантное содержимому">`. Описание тоже должно содержать ключевые слова
- Имела бы `<title>`, содержащий ключевые слова
- Имела бы контент, содержащий ключевые слова
- Везде, где необходимо содержание ключевых слов, они должны включаться органично. Не слишком много и не слишком мало. Предложения с ними должны согласовываться со структурой языка.
- Желательно выделять ключевые слова там где делается на них акцент
- Желательно, чтобы ключевые слова присутствовали в заголовках `<h1>` и ниже
- Желательно, чтобы в изображениях был бы атрибут `alt` с ключевым словом
- Желательно, чтобы страница присутствовала бы в `sitemap.xml`
- Желательно, чтобы ключевые слова присутствовали в пути к странице на сайте
- Необходимо, чтобы `robots.txt` не запрещал бы индексирование страницы

Кроме того, следует помнить, что в поисковиках Вы конкурируете с десятками тысяч похожих страниц, поэтому успешность поиска зависит не только от структуры и контента, то также и от ссылочной массы на Ваш ресурс и её качества.

Comment: Ни Google, ни Яндекс, ни Bing давно уже не используют мета-тег keywords. И для Google ЧПУ транслитом равнозначны URL'ам с бессмысленным набором символов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.html